# Storing dynamic sql's result into a variable

Tags: sql, dynamic

I have a following Cursor:

```
DECLARE MY_CURSOR Cursor
FOR 
SELECT [DB_NAME],[SCHEMA_NAME],[TABLE_NAME],[COLUMN_NAME]  FROM dbo.Data_Profile_Stats
Open My_Cursor
DECLARE @DB_NAME nvarchar(500),@SCHEMA_NAME  nvarchar(500),@TABLE_NAME  nvarchar(500),@COLUMN_NAME  nvarchar(500), @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @MAX_NUMBER NVARCHAR(255), @MIN_NUMBER INT, @NULL_COUNT INT, @BLANK_COUNT INT, @ZERO_COUNT INT,@DISTINCT_COUNT INT
Fetch NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @DB_NAME,@SCHEMA_NAME,@TABLE_NAME,@COLUMN_NAME 
While (@@FETCH_STATUS  = 0)
BEGIN

SELECT  @DB_NAME,@SCHEMA_NAME,@TABLE_NAME,@COLUMN_NAME

SET @QUERY='SELECT MAX('+@DB_NAME+'.'+@SCHEMA_NAME+'.'+@TABLE_NAME+'.'+@COLUMN_NAME+') FROM '+@DB_NAME+'.'+@SCHEMA_NAME+'.'+@TABLE_NAME
--SET @MAX_NUMBER=exec sp_executesql @QUERY
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @QUERY, N'@MAX_NUMBER NVARCHAR(255) OUTPUT', @MAX_NUMBER=@MAX_NUMBER OUTPUT
SELECT @MAX_NUMBER
--SET @QUERY='UPDATE [dbo].[Data_Profile_Stats] SET MAX_NUMBER='+CAST(@MAX_NUMBER AS VARCHAR(10))+' WHERE [DB_NAME]='+''''+@DB_NAME+''''+' AND SCHEMA_NAME='+''''+@SCHEMA_NAME+''''+' AND TABLE_NAME='+''''+@TABLE_NAME+''''+' AND COLUMN_NAME='+''''+@COLUMN_NAME+''''
--exec sp_executesql @QUERY

FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @DB_NAME,@SCHEMA_NAME,@TABLE_NAME,@COLUMN_NAME 
END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
GO
```

In the above query, I am seeing the result of the EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL but not able to see the value of @MAX_NUMBER in the next line

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not setting @MAX_NUMBER.  Try this:

```
SET @QUERY='SELECT @MAX_NUMBER=MAX('+@DB_NAME+'.'+@SCHEMA_NAME+'.'+@TABLE_NAME+'.'+@COLUMN_NAME+') FROM '+@DB_NAME+'.'+@SCHEMA_NAME+'.'+@TABLE_NAME;
```